# Passing const variable between member functions to be index of array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, indexing, constants

I have tried to solve this, but I can't. I have a class definition and I want a member function (siz) to return a constant value to another member function (abc). This value is used as maximum index in an array declaration in that function. But this doesn't seems to work. Here is a simplified version:

```
class bin {
    constexpr int siz();
public:
    void abc();
};

constexpr int bin::siz() {
    const int sizz = sizeof(int) * 8;
}

void bin::abc() {
    char arr[siz()];   // compiler: this expression didn't evaluate as constant (¿?)
};
```

However, this other very similar code (but using simple functions) does compile...

```
constexpr int siz() {
    const int sizz = sizeof(int) * 8;
    return sizz;
}

int main() {
    char arr[siz()];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `constexpr int bin::siz()` is a function, so it must return a result, doesn't it? I do not see `return` statement.

Comment: Yes, I oversimplificated there. But the original code has the return statements, so they are not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure but I think the problem is that in `bin::abc`, the object can be anything at run time. Hence, `bin::siz()` cannot be evaluated at compile time.

The following works fine

```
int main()
{
   bin b;
   char arr[b.siz()];
}
```

after changing `bin` to:

```
class bin {
public:
    constexpr int siz();
};

constexpr int bin::siz() {
    return sizeof(int) * 8;
}
```

If `siz` does not depend on the state of the object, as in your posted code, I suggest making it a `static` member function.

The following works fine for me.

```
class bin {
  public:
    static constexpr int siz();
    void abc() const;
};

constexpr int bin::siz() {
  return sizeof(int) * 8;
}

void bin::abc() const {
  char arr[siz()];
}

int main()
{
  bin b;
  char arr[b.siz()];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it worked just by putting static to siz. Thank you very much! I supposse that the creation of an object of type bin implies that it's not posible to have a constant member function. However, this problems make me feel that sometimes I have limited my freedom (in some way). What if I want an array that could be created and initialized many times, with different sizes (different indexes)? The rules say the value for that index must be constant...